# Complex Jensen inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

> Let $f:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{R}$ be a convex function (thus $f((1-t)z+tw)\leq (1-t)f(z)+tf(w)$) for all complex $z,w$ and all $0\leq t\leq 1$, and $X$ be a complex random variable with $X$ and $f(X)$ both absolutely integrable. Show that
>   $$f(\mathbf{E}X)\leq \mathbf{E}f(X).$$

I know how to prove it in the real case, if $f:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ is a convex function, then for every $x_0\in\mathbf{R}$, one can find a real number $c$ depending on $x_0$ such that 
$$f(x)\geq f(x_0)+c(x-x_0)\quad (*).$$
but (*) doesn't work in the complex case, any ideas on how to prove it?

Comment: Likewise, there exists $v$ such that $f(x)\geqslant f(x_0)+\langle v,x-x_0\rangle$ for every $x$.

Comment: @Did That is there is a $v$ such that $f(z)\geq f(z_0)+v(\overline{z}-\overline{z}_0)$. Could you give more hints? how to determine the complex number $v$?

Comment: More generally, prove it for convex $f : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$.